# How to validate user with SimpleMembership

Tags: simplemembership

I am using SimpleMembership for user login stuff in my web application. I wrote a console that actually access my web application classes to avoid duplicate code. However, since my console application doesn't have anything related to user sessions the Login method doesn't work.

But is there a way to validate a user only using the SimpleMembership? In case i have to do it manually.. how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

[Validating user in SimpleMembership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875571/validating-user-in-simplemembership)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.validateuser(v=vs.111).aspx