# Validating user in SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net, simplemembership

What is the alternative to [Membership.ValidateUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx) in SimpleMembership? I use `WebSecurity.Login` to validate the current user, but I have a situation where a user has to enter their password again to change some user settings. Should I just use `WebSecurity.Login` again? Seems like overkill.

Comment: You can work it arround Login out the user, store the url that will be used to redirect after the login, login the user again, and then redirect it

Comment: Thanks for the note, but I'm looking for a better method.

Comment: Maybe, Redirect the user to an alternate login page that makes him enter the credentials, then if its all ok redirect it to a NonAction, that can be acessed only by server!

Comment: Thanks again, but that's still hackish. In old Membership I could just call `ValidateUser` and all was good. I'm holding out hope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also needed to just validate a user in SimpleMembership and I think I found a good solution. You just need to grab the membership provider and call the method from there. Here is how I did it.

```
public static bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
{
    var membership = (WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
    return membership.ValidateUser(userName, password);
}
```

I created unit test for this and verified that it works. You can get a [list of the methods available for this membership provider here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

I added this to the open source project [SimpleSecurity](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/), which looks at ways to extend SimpleMembership and provides examples on how to use SimpleMembership.  It also [decouples SimpleMembership from your MVC application](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/03/decoupling-simplemembership-from-your.html).